# Why is LegendreQ[1/2,x] complex-valued for x>1?

Tags: special-functions

Something is strange with $\sf LegendreQ$.
Let $x>1$.
I wonder why $\sf LegendreQ[\frac12,x]$ is complex-valued, and the following two codes do not give the same results:

```
LegendreQ[1/2,x]

Pi/2/(2*x)^(3/2)*Hypergeometric2F1[5/4,3/4,2,1/x^2]
```

(whose identity is given by Equation 8.820.2 of Gradshteyn & Ryzhik, 7th Ed.)

Thank you for your interest and time.

Comment: Please post code rather than LaTeX.

Comment: Also, you should not use the `bugs` tag until the behavior is confirmed to be a bug by the community or by Wolfram support.

Comment: The code is posted. Thanks for the proper tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have access to the book right now, but it probably states

```
LegendreQ[1/2, 0, 3, x] == Pi/2/(2 x)^(3/2) Hypergeometric2F1[5/4, 3/4, 2, 1/x^2]
```

Comment: I looked it up: the pre-factor works out to $\pi/(4 \sqrt{2})$ rather than $\pi/2$, but the rest holds as you wrote it.

Comment: ${\sf LegendreQ}[1/2,0,3,x]$ works. Thank you. By the way, the equality holds for $x>0$ according to $\it \text{www.wolframalpha.com}$. Somewhat confusing.

Answer (score 2):

As the documentation says, `LegendreQ[n, m, a, z]` gives Legendre functions of type `a`. The default is type 1. `LegendreQ` of types 1, 2, and 3 are defined in terms of `LegendreP` of these types, and have the same branch cut structure. Type 3 functions have a single branch cut from $-\infty$ to $+1$. So, as in the answer above, you need to specify type 3. And

```
Plot[{LegendreQ[1/2, 0, 3, x], 
      Pi/2/(2 x)^(3/2) Hypergeometric2F1[5/4, 3/4, 2, 1/x^2]}, {x, 1, 5}]
```

looks fine.

Comment: Beyond $x>1$, the equality holds for $x>0$ according to $\it \text{www.wolframalpha.com}$. This confuses me.